# How/Shall I keep libc and kernel in sync?

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel, c, glibc

If I compile latest kernel from kernel.org, make a deb package and install it on my Debian system, shall I worry about libc (and any other libraries?) and kernel being out-of-sync?

I vaguely understand that kernel developers try hard to not break API/ABI exposed to userspace, but I guess once in a while breaks do happen, at least for some legitimate reasons? If so, is there a place that documents the mapping of working libc version vs kernel version?

Comment: You mostly would worry about libc or header file upgrades if you actually want to use new features. Unless then you don't need to worry (on the other hand not compiling your own kernel is even more reliable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linus is tougher on userspace breakage than pretty much any of his other policies. Breaks are way rarer than "once in a while", essentially unheard-of. Just don't worry about it at all.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph. The reason I am asking is that kernel build generates three packages, one of them is linux-libc-dev, which will install a bunch of files in /usr/include/linux folder. These files seem to output a bunch of kernel headers into userspace, does that mean only addition but no deletion/replacement can happen, so that exposed API would not break?

Comment: @QnA They should be safe too.